# Public debt and GDP in post-socialistic countries

Tags: gdp, debt

Why is public debt in % of GDP in post-socialistic countries of Eastern Europe is less than in countries of Western Europe.

Some arguments, opinions or articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not generally true. If you [look at](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_public_debt) gross debt, the Western countries of Finland, Denmark and Norway have lower debt ratios (53%,50%,34%) than post-socialistic Croatia (80%) and Hungary (79%). If you look at net debt, these Western countries have even better numbers.

So right now the correct answer is that your premise is not true.

Your statement is probably true in some form (e.g. on 'average', whatever that would mean in this context, or given some specific Western countries), but please make it exact and back it up with a source. (Perhaps in a new question, seeing that I put effort into answering your current one. [Changing it post-answer](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/editing-answered-questions) would be somewhat unsporting.)